# Cannot perform ctrl + click in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot use cmd + click in eclipse, if I am pressing cmd and move mouse to over any expression I get a popup show such as picture but I cannot click. Does anyone know the solution?
Thanks
Regards

[image]

Comment: what do you mean you cannot user cmd + click? What gives you the impression it is supposed to click?

Comment: Dear Kata, did you see screen shot? For e.q. If i want to click "Open Declaration in layout/splash.xml" , there is a scrollbar so i cannot click

Comment: By holding control(in windows) I can drag the scrollbars. You can do the same if you pressing and holding cmd button as you hover over the scrollbar

Comment: Dear Dibya, I cannot drag, tried it before, if you looked at screenshot, scrollbars are over on items,  I can give remote access to anyone because i am going crazy and can not perform cmd + click